# remove model in collection and fire remove event - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

how do I remove remove a  model in collection and make the remove event fire . I tried  `people.remove([{ name: "joe3" }]);` but it wont work.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function () {
        console.log(" person is initialized");
    },
    defaults: {
        name: "underfined",
        age:"underfined"
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log("people collection is initialized");
        this.bind('add', this.onModelAdded, this);
        this.bind('remove', this.onModelRemoved, this);
    },
    model: Person,
    onModelAdded: function(model, collection, options) {
        console.log("options = ", options);
        alert("added");
    },
    onModelRemoved: function (model, collection, options) {
        console.log("options = ", options);
        alert("removed");
    },
});

//var person = new Person({ name: "joe1" });
var people = new People();



//people.add([{ name: "joe2" }]);
people.add([{ name: "joe1" }]);
people.add([{ name: "joe2" }]);
people.add([{ name: "joe3" }]);
people.add([{ name: "joe4" }]);
people.add([{ name: "joe5" }]);

people.remove([{ name: "joe3" }]);



console.log(people.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

By doing:

```
people.remove([{ name: "joe3" }]);
```

you don't remove a model, because you pass just an plain object which is not connected to `people` collection. Instead you could do something like this:

```
people.remove(people.at(2));
```

Or:

```
var model = new Person({name: "joe3"});
people.add(model);
...
people.remove(model);
```

will work as well.

So you need to reference actual model object from a collection;

http://jsfiddle.net/kD9Xu/

Comment: thnaks - one more question please - how do I get the values of the properties of the model in the removed function :     onModelRemoved: function (model, collection, options) {
        console.log("options = ", options);
        alert("removed" + model.attributes.name + " " + model.attributes.age + "      has been removed");
    },

Comment: I have a related question: does Backbone.Model's `pop` method fire the remove event? (it doesn't seem to...)

Comment: @Ziggy Yes, of course. Collection's `pop` method will remove a model from collection and fire `remove` event, unless it's suppressed with `silent` option.

Answer (score 38):

For anyone else looking for a remove where, you can simply chain it with a collection.where call. like so to remove all items matching the search:

```
people.remove(people.where({name: "joe3"}));
```

see [Backbone collection.where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where)

Comment: Yea this seemed to be what I was looking for too. Simple, straight-forward answer that works.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is shorter a little and fires the *remove* event for a collection as well:

```
people.at(2).destroy();
// OR
people.where({name: "joe2"})[0].destroy();
```

> Triggers a "destroy" event on the model, which will bubble up through any collections that contain it.. http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy

Answer (score 5):

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "underfined",
        age:"underfined"
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.bind('remove', this.onModelRemoved, this);
    },
    model: Person,
    onModelRemoved: function (model, collection, options) {
        alert("removed");
    },
    getByName: function(name){
       return this.filter(function(val) {
          return val.get("name") === name;
        })
    }
});

var people = new People();

people.add(new Person({name:"joe1"}));
people.add(new Person({name:"joe2"}));
people.remove(people.getByName("joe1"));

console.info(people.toJSON());
```

Comment: then why not removeByName()

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove "[0]" you can use the following code:

```
people.findWhere({name: "joe2"}).destroy();
```